# a lot of angular 2+ components require System.js for fine tuning but Angular CLI not using it

Tags: angular, angular-cli, systemjs

A lot of angular 2+ components require systemjs or fine tuning but Angular CLI not using it.
For example I have problem with ag-grid-angular component , after installing  I have a lot of errors , but all the sources in stackoverflow and other sites have solutions which require modifying Systemjs configuration ,[like this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36453594/ag-grid-error-failed-to-load-resource-ag-grid-ng2-main-js)

I have a lot of problems finding proper working compnents like autocompleter ,datetimepicker , etc. , which is not requiering systemjs.

Comment: Those aren't Angular components, those are libraries. Angular CLI uses Webpack instead of systemJS. If you want already made components, take a look at **[Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/)**

Comment: Is it webpack ready or still requires systemjs ?

Comment: It is webpack ready, and easy to install (the procedure is explained very well)

Comment: It's ok , but why those libraries are not webpack ready ?

Comment: I'm not the dev of those libraries, you should ask them instead !

Comment: I am not very experienced angular developer and it's too strange for me that a lot of libraries had that problem .I thought that there was some issue that i didn't know.Thanks a lot for advise.

Comment: If you're a beginner, then I recommend you stick to the Angular repository. Don't try using libraries on the side, because Angular provides all you need. Once you get some knowledge, then you can browse libraries and use them. I tell you that from my personal experience, but feel free to not listen to me if you want ti skip steps.